# SOCK_DGRAM socket recv thread-safe?

Tags: sockets, network-programming, datagram, unix-socket

Are UNIX SOCK_DGRAM sockets thread-safe for recv() method?

If multiple threads are calling recv() on socket, are both guaranteed to get one clean UDP packet each or is there a chance of data getting mixed up?

Will the behavior be affected by whether socket is in blocking or non-blocking mode? Any pointers to documentation would be highly appreciated.

Comment: `recv()`, like all system calls, is atomic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Calling `recv()` from multiple threads is a safe operation. If the socket is a datagram socket then each recv returns a unique datagram that is not mixed up with other datagrams.

Posix standard explicitly enumerates all standard functions that are unsafe:

> 2.9.1 Thread-Safety
>
> All functions defined by this volume of POSIX.1-2017 shall be
> thread-safe, except that the following functions1 need not be
> thread-safe.
>
> asctime() basename() catgets() crypt() ctime()
> ....

There are almost 100 unsafe functions and further functions that are safe under certain conditions only. `recv()` is not there. See [POSIX.1-2017 2.9.1 Thread-Safety](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/V2_chap02.html#tag_15_09).